# Preventing the installation of kernel drivers on Windows

Tags: windows, kernel

Is there a way to prevent programs from installing kernel modules on a Windows 10 system? either something that just denies the permission to add kernel modules (even if they are signed), for example, that makes the installation of a game that has a kernelmode anticheat fail, or prompts the user with a dialog, to select the action (allow or deny).

Either a Windows feature to do so (By editing registry entries, Group Policy Objects, or anything else), if there isn't, any idea on how it can be done? (any program that does it, or idea on how it can be done by low-level programming).

Comment: I think the best you are going to get is denying users admin.

Comment: @FrankThomas Allowing installation of software in %programfiles% is not something I'd like to prevent ideally, I come from a Linux background, and I'm looking for something like capabilities (CAP_SYS_MODULE would prevent adding/removing kernel modules on Linux), I don't know on Windows, if there is something like that fine-grained permissions (Administrator permissions but with some restrictions for example)

Comment: You may need to defeat the Microsoft Catalogue updates. You can try turning Driver Updates OFF in Update Settings but some drivers are very insistent .

Comment: why don't we start with Why you want to do such a thing. Windows doesn't really allow you to add or remove permissions from roles.